# БОТ автоответчик (что такое персептрон?)

Tags: delphi, php, java, бот, c++

В общем идея не свежа, но интересует следующие

Есть ли алгоритмы которые считывают предложение и понимают о чем собственно в предложении речь чтобы потом дать ответ на него
(допустим база слов какая то и т.д.)

И еще что такое персептрон? Я не понял что это такое (понял что программа сама обучается)

Может есть простенький пример на эту тему?
и кто знает обьясните по простому

вот [исходник моего бота на delphi](http://nagon.net/uploads/files/80/80-zjrrp4axy.zip)

конечно до чего то серьезного еще далеко
хочу его усовершенствовать

> Некто_23:51:46_привет
>
> Вы_23:51:48_привет
>
> Некто_23:51:55_парень??
>
> Вы_23:51:57_да
>
> Некто_23:52:03_ураааааа
>
> Вы_23:52:06_что не так?
>
> Некто_23:52:25_просто ты первый парень
> которого я встретила
>
> Вы_23:52:27_=)
>
> Некто_23:52:28_
>
> Некто_23:52:38_как тебя зовут??
>
> Вы_23:52:39_клава
>
> Некто_23:52:56_Меня Женя,очень приятно
>
> Вы_23:52:57_щас будет приятнее
>
> Некто_23:53:09_
>
> Некто_23:53:26_Интересно-интересно
>
> Вы_23:53:27_???
>
> Некто_23:54:03_Это я должна спросить,в
> каком смысле приятнее??
>
> Вы_23:54:06_давай
>
> Некто_23:54:19_что давать???
>
> Вы_23:54:21_а ты как думаешь?
>
> Некто_23:55:03_Не понимаю, объясни
> мне))
>
> Вы_23:55:06_;)
>
> Некто_23:55:34_
>
> Некто_23:56:09_сколько лет???
>
> Вы_23:56:12_19
>
> Некто_23:56:27_Шикарный возраст))
>
> Вы_23:56:30_16
>
> Некто_23:56:59_Ну что расскажешь??
>
> Вы_23:57:00_меня прет)
>
> Некто_23:57:09_От чего??
>
> Вы_23:57:09_от тебя)
>
> Некто_23:57:28_
>
> Некто_23:57:47_да,я такая))
>
> Вы_23:57:48_=)
>
> Некто_23:58:12_Откуда ты??
>
> Вы_23:58:12_Украина
>
> Некто_23:58:20_город
>
> Вы_23:58:21_Москва
>
> Некто_23:59:26_А я из Одессы,может я
> покажусь дурой,но мне кажеться,что
> Москва э
>
> Вы_23:59:27_да так
>
> Некто_23:59:34_это Россия
>
> Вы_23:59:36_да)
>
> Некто_23:59:48_Я умная))
>
> Вы_23:59:48_=)
>
> Некто_00:00:13_Чем увлекаешься??
>
> Вы_00:00:15_это как?
>
> Некто_00:00:29_Твоё хобби
>
> Вы_00:00:30_=)
>
> Некто_00:00:54_
>
> Некто_00:01:11_ну так,чем
> увлекаешься???
>
> Вы_00:01:12_о чем это ты?
>
> Некто_00:01:34_Вокалом,танцами,рисованием?7
>
> Вы_00:01:36_да
>
> Некто_00:01:49_Что да,чем именно??
>
> Вы_00:01:51_а ты как думаешь?
>
> Некто_00:02:05_Вокалом,может быть
>
> Вы_00:02:06_я вся твоя
>
> Некто_00:02:42_ты точно парень???
>
> Вы_00:02:45_нет
>
> Некто_00:03:00_О боже и тебе не 19
>
> Вы_00:03:03_;)
>
> Некто_00:03:27_Так,всё с тобой понятно
> Клава,пока
>
> //———
>
> Некто_00:09:12_привет)
>
> Вы_00:09:15_прив
>
> Некто_00:09:22_ты от куда?
>
> Вы_00:09:24_Беларуссия
>
> Некто_00:09:32_я тож)а город?
>
> Вы_00:09:33_Москва
>
> Некто_00:09:49_ого,у мя гомель,ты есть
> вк?
>
> Вы_00:09:51_да
>
> Некто_00:10:05_скинь ссылку)а я те
> свою
>
> Вы_00:10:06_для секса или так?
>
> Некто_00:10:11_так
>
> Вы_00:10:12_;)
>
> Некто_00:10:18_vk.com/id163748637
>
> Вы_00:10:21_чпокаться будеш?
>
> Некто_00:10:37_ты нармальный?
>
> Вы_00:10:39_что?
>
> Некто_00:10:54_ничё…
>
> Вы_00:10:57_и…
>
> Некто_00:11:07_ссылку скинь
>
> Вы_00:11:09_вначале расскажи о себе
>
> Некто_00:11:28_ну я алёна,мне
> 14,рисую,пою,танецую
>
> Вы_00:11:30_:)
>
> Некто_00:11:42_ссылку довай
>
> Вы_00:11:45_вначале расскажи о себе
>
> Некто_00:11:54_рассказала уже
>
> Вы_00:11:57_ты о чем?
>
> Некто_00:12:12_скок те лет?
>
> Вы_00:12:15_15
>
> Некто_00:12:42_лан поки(ес чё перейди
> по ссылке и найди мя вк
>
> Вы_00:12:45_да
>
> Некто_00:13:01_всё пока)найди мя вк!
>
> Вы_00:13:03_да

Comment: нужно как то организовывать связи во время беседы в виде дерева и запоминать их

Comment: такой персептрончик у вас неделю будет обучаться

Answer (score 3):

Для самообразования, прочти о тесте Тьюринга, а также посмотри коментарии к теме
[Тест Тьюринга](http://habrahabr.ru/post/69758/)

Answer (score 2):

Если есть доступ к Интернету используй Яндекс и его апи, более менее ответ будешь получать.

Если делать полностью локальное приложение, то наверное толковый словарь нужен какой то, потом в вопросе выделять существительные и на основании их выводить из словаря ответ.
Это самый простой но и самый топорный вариант.

Анализ предложения задача далеко не тривиальная и подключать нужно специалистов гуманитариев.

а персептрон это одна из первых нейросетей, подробней можно прочитать в вики [персептрон](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перцептрон)